# using canvas destination-out in animation not working in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I tried to implement an animation in canvas with "destination-out", but it does not working in chrome and firefox. But it does work in safari.

Chrome; [image capture from chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Coak8.png)

Safari;
[image capture from safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVKev.jpg)

Could it be know what I'm missing ?

Code example would be much understandable..

```js
const $video = document.getElementById("video")
const $canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const $mask = document.getElementById("mask");

const ctx = $canvas.getContext("2d");
const maskCtx = $mask.getContext("2d");

maskCtx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
maskCtx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50)

const run = () => {
  ctx.drawImage($video, 0, 0, 300, 200)
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
  ctx.drawImage($mask, 0, 0, 300, 200)

  window.requestAnimationFrame(run)
}

$video.onloadeddata = () => {
  run()
 
}
```

```css
video, canvas {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<video id="video" autoplay muted loop src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="mask"></canvas>
```

Comment: AFK, so can't test right now, but I doubt it works in Safari, and if it does that's a bug. You are not resetting the globalCompositeOperation to source-over so the next time you'll draw the video over the full canvas, you'll just have transparent pixels left, for ever.

Comment: Wow cool, thanks :) It does work indeed !

I added this from first line on run function. 
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";